# How can I use multiple Cinder sources?

Tags: juju, openstack

Is there a way to have multiple cinder sources and have this represented in juju?

I know you can deploy multiple neutron-gateways, but I was hoping to create a SSD ceph / cinder source, as well as a non SSD ceph/cinder source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by deploying the cinder-backend of your choice multiple times. For example: if you had two physical EMC VNX backends you would deploy the cinder-vnx charm twice:

```
juju deploy cinder-vnx backend-alpha
juju deploy cinder-vnx backend-beta
```

When you reconfigured and related these two backends to cinder they'd each get their own stanza in the cinder configuration:

```
juju add-relation cinder backend-alpha
juju add-relation cinder backend-beta
```

You'll need to find the Cinder plugin charm you're using, deploy it and configure them to point one at SSD and the other at your spinning disks, name them maybe `backend-fast` and `backend-slow` (or any name, doesn't even have to be prefixed with backend) relate them to cinder and you've got two backends in cinder ready for consumption.

Comment: Will this be exposed in horizon as a region / source?